# Vue.js How to condition render tr in table

Tags: vue.js

my demo sample : [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/uvwkvsox/)

I want to render per column with 3 rows data , like

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <strong class="blue">[{{item.orderId}}]</strong><br>
            {{item.title}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <strong class="blue">[{{item.orderId}}]</strong><br>
        {{item.title}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <strong class="blue">[{{item.orderId}}]</strong><br>
        {{item.title}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

How Can I do , thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

you can slice the array and use a nested loop in Vue template.

https://jsfiddle.net/9Lf7zo4g/2/

```
 computed: {
   sliced: function() {
     const sliced = []
     const chunk = 3
     for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + chunk) {
       sliced.push(this.data.slice(i, i + chunk))
     }
     return sliced
  }
}
```